# Terminal shortcut key stopped working - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

After last reboot my gnome-terminal shortcut key stopped working, it is set under settings to be Ctrl + Alt + T, but even when I change to something else like Super + T it doesn't work even though Super + T could open the web browser.

Last things I did was install docky and hide the Dash to Dock via dconf (still available when I click Activities in top left). Also wanted to the following https://samtinkers.wordpress.com/2016/06/13/fix-blurry-terminal-icon-in-plankdocky/ but it seems like the gnome-terminal.desktop is not present in /usr/share/applications.

Also tried Reset All.. button in the Keyboard Shortcut settings. Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but clicking the terminal shortcut key makes the scrollbar focus blink in firefox

Answer (score 0):

A workaround was to add a new keyboard shortcut to the gnome-terminal. The Launch Terminal shortcut is still not working

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Check if `x-terminal-emulator` opens a terminal.

If not you can try the following:

Check whether `/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator` exists:
`ls /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator`

a) Doesn't exis; create the link:
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator`

b) Check the selected terminal app by running:
`sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`